# Is it a bad idea to have route as a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, routes

I was about to do

```
rails g scaffold Route
```

But I didn't know if it's a bad idea to have a Route model and Routes controller and if it would conflict with config/routes.rb

I don't see "route" listed under the reserved words at http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords so I'm assuming it's ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there would not be an issue with the names conflicting.  But I would avoid it just out of convention.  Routes are something that we as RoR developers discuss frequently and having a route for your routes could lead to some interesting conversations.